# Select Query From MSSQL group by weekly data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I used the following query with sql server 2008 to select group by records.

```
     Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) AS ljoin,
     Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) AS rjoin, DATEPART(wk, Date) AS WeekNumber,
     CASE 
     WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date]))) < YEAR(Min([date]))
     THEN CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, 0 ,GETDATE())), 0) AS      Varchar(50))   + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
    ELSE
    Cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date])) AS Varchar(50)) + ' TO ' +       Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
    END AS  DateRange
    FROM Pairs_Details  where userid='jitu'
    Group By userid,DATEPART(wk, Date)
```

it return following result. for perticular userid ='jitu'

```
   userid   ljoin   rjoin   WeekNumber  DateRange                             
   jitu 1   2   1   Jan  1 2014 12:00AM TO Jan  6 2013 12:00AM
   jitu 1   1   2   Jan  6 2014 12:00AM TO Jan 12 2014 12:00AM
   jitu 1   0   3   Jan 13 2014 12:00AM TO Jan 19 2014 12:00AM
   jitu 2   0   5   Jan 27 2014 10:00PM TO Feb  2 2014 10:00PM
```

It started with 2012-08-06 since the cycle should be start(2014-01-01)monday to Sunday. I've tried googling about an hour or so and it seems that no result fits with my problem, I Hope someone could help me there are my following table, data and desire output which I want

`Pairs_Details` table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pairs_Details](
[sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[userid] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL,
[ljoin] [int] NULL,
[rjoin] [int] NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example data:

```
   sno  userid              date                            ljoin rjoin
   1    jitu                2013-01-01 00:00:00.000         1   NULL
   2    jitu                2014-01-02 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
   3    tetu1234            2014-01-03 00:00:00.000     1   NULL
   4    jitu                2014-01-04 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
   5    saurbh123           2014-01-05 00:00:00.000     1   NULL
   6    jitu                2014-01-06 00:00:00.000         1   NULL
   9    saurbh123           2014-01-12 00:00:00.000         NULL    1
  10    jitu                2014-01-13 00:00:00.000         1   NULL
  11    rajeev123           2014-01-29 22:00:13.000         1   NULL
  12    saurbh123           2014-01-29 22:00:13.000         1   NULL
  13    jitu                2014-01-29 22:00:13.000         1   NULL
  14    rajeev123           2014-01-29 22:01:03.000         NULL    1
  15    saurbh123           2014-01-29 22:01:03.000         1   NULL
  16    jitu                2014-01-29 22:01:03.000         1   NULL
  7         tetu1234        2014-01-07 00:00:00.000         NULL    1
  8         jitu                2014-01-08 00:00:00.000         NULL    1
```

i want the following result

```
 userid ljoin   rjoin   WeekNumber  DateRange                               pair        
   jitu 1   2   1      Jan  1 2014 12:00AM TO Jan  6 2013 12:00AM          1
   jitu 1   1   2      Jan  6 2014 12:00AM TO Jan 12 2014 12:00AM          1
   jitu 1   0   3      Jan 13 2014 12:00AM TO Jan 19 2014 12:00AM          0
   jitu 2   0   5      Jan 27 2014 10:00PM TO Feb  2 2014 10:00PM          0
```

this can be done using following query.

```
Select Case When ljoin <= rjoin  Then ljoin Else rjoin End As pair from Pairs_Details
```

but how this query can be used with above query pleae any one can tell us

please any can help me. so that we can retrieve desired result

thanks.

Comment: Please explain what the query is meant to return

Answer (score 1):

--Updated Query I tried to get desired output but still you need to just play around as per your requirement;  All the Best!!!

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT  userid,
Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) AS lJoin,
Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) AS rjoin, DATEPART(wk, Date) AS WeekNumber,
CASE 
WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date]))) < YEAR(Min([date]))
THEN CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, 0 ,GETDATE())), 0) AS Varchar(50))   + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
ELSE
Cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date])) AS Varchar(50)) + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
END AS  DateRange
FROM Pairs_Details
Group By userid,DATEPART(wk, Date)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply naveen kumar ji  but this query return following result          jitu 2 3 Jan  1 2014 12:00AM TO Jan  8 2014 12:00AM
saurbh123 1 NULL Jan  5 2014 12:00AM TO Jan  5 2014 12:00AM
tetu1234 1 1 Jan  3 2014 12:00AM TO Jan  7 2014 12:00AM

Comment: Change above query with ISNULL(ljoin,0) AND ISNULL(rjoin,0)

Comment: Thanks Naveen kumar ji for your reply
but this query does not return my desire result so please read my above query and desired output and please provide solution or give any idea  my desired result is as follows Desired output weekly: for perticular userid 'jitu'

 userid | ljoin | rjoin | DATERANGE                                           |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  jitu  |     2 |   2   |   2014-01-21 15:48:24.00 TO 2014-01-27 16:40:05.000 |

Comment: Thanks Naveen ji But i think you are not understand my question please first review my whole question then provide solution and you are so close my answer please review my full question and details query i changed my query according my requirement.and i also mention output of my query but my query return value from   2014-01-06 to 2014-01-012 and 2014-01-13 to 2014-01-19 and i want my cycle start from 2014-01-01

Comment: thank you vary much Naveen Kumar ji  you provide exactly same solution which i want

Comment: thanks Neveen Kumar ji for youre valuable solution now i want some changes in my desired result  which can be done using following query  " Select Case When ljoin <= rjoin  Then ljoin Else rjoin End As pair from Pairs_Details" but how this query can be merged with your query please suggest us which you provided me

Comment: use this way "Case When Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) <= Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) Then Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) Else Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0))End AS PAIR" rest is same no change in the select statement

Comment: Dear Naveen kumar ji how to display this data in griedview in c# .net because when we use  your query in c#.net with griedview  then it return following errror.   "A field or property with the name 'PAIR' was not found on the selected data source."  please give any idea thanks.